# django Keyerror password

Tags: django, python-3.x, keyerror

I am trying to create a edit user profile feature which allows users to edit their profile info. When I click on submit in the form it is showing as keyerror password at albums/profile/edit.

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P6JH.png)

Views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.views.generic import View
from albums.models import Album, Song

from .forms import Userforms, EditProfileForm

class Profile_edit(View):
    form_class = EditProfileForm
    template_name = 'accounts/edit_profile.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from django import forms

class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password'}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.Profile_edit.as_view(), name='Profile_edit'),
```

edit_profile.html:

```
{% extends 'albums/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block albums_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">

<div class="panel panel-default">

<div class="panel-body">

{% extends 'albums/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block albums_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  {% csrf_token %}

  {% include 'albums/form-template.html' %}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is it possible that "password" is a reserved keyword somewhere in Django's form infrastructure? Can you post more of the traceback so that we can see where in `views.py` things are going awry? The exception location shown in your screen shot isn't very helpful.

Comment: `fields = {'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password'}` It seems odd that you're enclosing this in curly braces, thus making it a set.  The examples I've seen use lists or tuples.  Maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a user instance to the form when initialising it, otherwise the form has no idea which user you are editing.

```
def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(instance=request.user)

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

Comment: Check in views.py  
it should be 
`password=cd['passowrd']` and not 
`password=cd['password']`
basically password is the reserve keyword